# Rails complex if

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I wonder what the beautiful way to output this in Rails.

```
order.items.min.user.email
```

I want to show the value of **email**, the only thing I know is **order** is not nil, however **items** and **user** might be nil.

The only way I see is

```
if !order.items.empty? 
  if !order.items.min.user.nil? 
    if !order.items.min.user.email.nil? 
      order.items.min.user.email
    end
  end
end
```

It looks like not the best way, do you know the better way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) (or [`try!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try-21) depending on your Rails3 version and how you want unknown methods to be handled):

```
order.items.try(:min).try(:user).try(:email)
```

`try` is an easy way to swallow `nil`s (and unknown methods depending on your Rails version) in a long method call chain.

Comment: call chain is too long, consider my answer below

Comment: @mu...you are awesome

Comment: He/she can also use andand gem.

Answer (score 7):

Consider this more elegant approach:

Order:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end
```

Item:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  delegate :email, to: :user, allow_nil: true, prefix: true # You can remove the prefix true and call item.email instead item.user_email
end
```

Then:

```
order.items.min.try(:user_email)
```

or:

```
order.items.min.try(:user_email).presence || "Not found"
```

Which will return the user's email or "Not found" in case items.min is nil, user is nil, or email is nil.

Comment: That's because it doesn't make sense an order item belonging to an user :). This is the law of demeter being applied.

Comment: Plus that line may be used in other parts of the application, which will indeed reduce the total complexity.